# JS push array into array not working

Tags: javascript

this is my code that doesn't working as expected, I don't want it to push same array into this array

```
var fruits = [];
var news={from,theword};

if (fruits.indexOf(news) <0){ // or .includes(news)

    fruits.push(news);}.
```

OUTPUT

```
[ { from: 'rubuno@.me',
    theword: 'birakma beni derken birakilirmi bu kadin ' },
  { from: 'rubuno@.me',
    theword: 'birakma beni derken birakilirmi bu kadin ' } ]
```

Comment: `news` is a invalid object .post with correct object format

Comment: Object is not a string, you can't search with indexOf here.

Comment: how can I do...

Comment: As wostex said. If you want to check if an Object is in an array you need to check the props of each Object.

Comment: without for loop its not possible?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `{from,theword}` on line 2 and `{from,theword}` on line 6 look the same, but they are actually different objects.

As an example, `{} === {}` returns `false`. Only primitives (strings, numbers, booleans, ...) are equal when they just look the same: `'a' === 'a'` returns `true`.

So if you change `{from,theword}` to `news` on line 6, it will point to the same object and your code will work (there will be only 1 object in the array).

Also, `{from,theword}` notation is quite new in javascript. Are you sure you want this? It's the same as saying `{from: from, theword: theword}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`Array#find`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwif19uM74_UAhXIPI8KHSwcDDEQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffind&usg=AFQjCNEJXKz25jH7wLT1dX55f_XDZ9QiRg&sig2=sOsVK7ZBi7vZZCXwLpDkiQ) method .Don't forget to add `!` in start with `if` condition

**Updated**

```js
var fruits = [{from: 'rubuno@ .me', theword: 'gelmis gecmis en guzel kadin sesi yuregine saglik funda'}, {  from: 'rubuno@ .me',  theword: 'gelmis gecmis en guzel kadin sesi yuregine saglik funda'}]
var news = { from: 'rubuno@ .me', theword: 'gelmis gecmis en guzel kadin sesi yuregine saglik funda'}

 if (!fruits.find(a => a.from == news.from && a.theword == news.theword)) { //check is present r not
      fruits.push(news); //then push is not inside the array
    }
    console.log(fruits) //is passing one time only
```

Comment: This code would work, but `!includes()` is just the same as `indexOf() < 0`. I think he is confused by the fact that `{}` isn't equal to `{}`.

Comment: still pushing same array into it, it says true,,,

Comment: with same code everytme it adds same array I see output and returns false I don't know why

Comment: var news={from:from,theword:theword};


console.log(fruits);

console.log(fruits.includes(news));
if (!fruits.includes(news)){

 fruits.push(news);

Comment: @user80268677 yes is false .because you are console.log it before the `push` statement .`fruits` still empty .That's why `news` not in array => return false. see my answer snippet i was added after the pushing

Comment: no I see full of fruits array three times of same of that its not null before check

Comment: console.log(fruits);
console.log(news);

console.log(fruits.includes(news));
if (!fruits.includes(news)){

Comment: [ { from: 'rubuno@ .me',
    theword: 'gelmis gecmis en guzel kadin sesi yuregine saglik funda' },
  { from: 'rubuno@ .me',
    theword: 'gelmis gecmis en guzel kadin sesi yuregine saglik funda' } ]
{ from: 'rubuno@ .me',
  theword: 'gelmis gecmis en guzel kadin sesi yuregine saglik funda' }
false

Comment: its node js btw